# Query to get difference depending on month

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 4 columns in my table ( ID,counter,month,year)

My task is to calculate difference between  counter of current month and counter of previous month of specific ID

For example:

```
ID    Counter     Month      Year 
1      57688       12        2017
1      89895        1        2018
2      35792        1        2018
3      12234        2        2018
```

Now if I want to find the difference between tow rows with the same ID (like the first two rows)
89895(Jan)-57688(dec)= 32207 will be the result

Keeping in mind the condition for changing from Jan 2018 to dec 2017

How can I do this task

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (The answer won't be the same.)

Comment: Could you add an example output on how it should look to make it a bit more clear?

Comment: your sample data doesnt match your question. You say `of previous month of specific ID` but no ID is repeated. Date related functions vary within different database providers so different database tags do make difficult giving an accurate version

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have SQL Server, your question is not clear about it.

```
declare @sampleData table(id int, [counter] int, [month] int, [year] int)

insert into @sampleData values 
(1, 57688, 12, 2017),
(1, 89895, 1, 2018),
(2, 35792, 1, 2018),
(2, 12234, 3, 2018);

select 
    id, [counter], [month], [year], 
    lag([counter],1,0) over (partition by id order by [year] asc, [month] asc) as previousCounter 
from 
    @sampleData
```

You can have previous or later results using `lag` or `lead` functions.You can check the doc at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql